# How to get the desired value for lat,long to display only the required portion of the map with Leaflet.js?

Tags: javascript, django, leaflet

I am trying to display a portion of a map with this amount of code:-

```
<div id="mapid" style="height: 280px; width: 1143px;">
    <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.js"></script>

    <script>
        var mymap = L.map("mapid").setView([5, 120], 13);

        L.tileLayer("http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
        }).addTo(mymap);
    </script>
</div>
```

But that displays this portion of the map:-
[image]

But I am trying to get this portion of the map:-

[image]

is there any tool I can optimize my code to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the view of the map with: `map.setView([lat,lng],zoom)`

For your example: `mymap.setView([-3.687845, 113.776067], 4);`

Or you can set the bounds (top left corner and right bottom corner) of the map, so the map is calculated what is the best zoom to contain the bounds.

```
var bounds = L.latLngBounds([6.884470, 94.897447],[-13.549102, 154.879214])
mymap.fitBounds(bounds)
```

But to answer your question, you can get the latlng when you click on the map with:

```
map.on('click',function(e){
    console.log(e.latlng);
});
```